# Cannot connect to virtual machine console

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I have a virtual machine created from an linux image (and powered on). I want to be able to access its console in VCenter, but right now I am getting this error:

```
"A secure connection to the host could not be established"
```

The console is a black screen with nothing on it and no interaction. This happens for any VM in VSphere. Bizarrely I can telnet in to the console port 902, but there doesn't even appear to be any attempt to connect to the console (checking tcp/ip traffic in Task Manager).

SSHing in is not possible because the reason I wanted console access to begin with was to run commands to set up an IP address for this machine.

Some facts: Opening an external console window does nothing (same error). I'm running Windows XP Professional (out of VirtualBox if it matters). My colleague on the exact same setup (same version of XP, same version of VCenter) can connect to the console just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when connecting to vcenter I needed to use https instead of http. Boy howdy, do I feel smart now.

Answer (score 0):

Does this problem happen when you connect directly to the ESX/ESXi ?
if not you have connection problem beetween esx and vcenter.

you can find here a list of common ports :
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=1012382&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&dialogID=312218113&stateId=1%200%20312216906#vCenter 4.x

Comment: How do I know which version of ESX this is using? (Vcenter version is 4.1.) Which port should I be trying?

Comment: when connecting to your vsphere client, select your host, you should see version on the upper part of the right pane.

Comment: I'm on ESXi 4.1.0 but I still haven't figured out how to connect directly yet.